# Set the subclass for `ECSlidingViewController`

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to add the ECSlidingViewController in my project, but I'm a novice on iOS and I'm not sure what to do in order to follow the instructions: "Add a UIViewController to your storyboards and set the subclass to `ECSlidingViewController`"

I've added the UIViewController, but now how do I set the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use storyboards, but it sounds like you  have to set custom class for this controller in identity inspector.

[image: xcode identity inspector]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, you added an UIViewController in StoryBoard named "InitialSlidingViewController". 
Then in InitialSlidingViewController.h, you should make the interface declaration as follows.

```
@interface InitialSlidingViewController : ECSlidingViewController
```

And please check the demo given by "ECSlidingViewController". You will understand it then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got class and subclass the wrong way around.

What you are creating is a class called `ECSlidingViewController` that is a subclass of `UIVIewController`.

In you ECSlidingViewController.h you should have the following...

```
@interface ECSlidingViewController : UIViewController
```

This means you are defining a class called `ECSlidingViewController` and it is a subclass of `UIViewController`.